# NVD3 chart is getting cut off near axes

Tags: nvd3.js

I'm working on a new chart type for NVD3 called lineWithFocusPlusSecondary. It has two graphs on top of each other. It's working well except for one problem: if the x values are dates, when you zoom in, the graph gets cut off in an unpleasant manner. This doesn't happen with the default lineChart so I've definitely done something wrong.

[image: Graph cut off]

I've put my code in this plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/9GzI0Jxi5qXZas3ljuBQ?p=preview

Would love some help :) It seems like the issue in the screenshot is that the x-axis domain goes until ~7:05pm but we don't have a data point until 7pm.

It could be something something to do with my onBrush function:

```
function onBrush(extent) {
    var processedData = processData(container.datum()),
      dataPrimary = processedData.dataPrimary,
      dataSecondary = processedData.dataSecondary,
      seriesPrimary = processedData.seriesPrimary,
      seriesSecondary = processedData.seriesSecondary;

    updateChartData(
      getIntegerExtent(extent),
      dataPrimary,
      dataSecondary,
      seriesPrimary,
      seriesSecondary
    );
  }

  function getIntegerExtent(extent) {
    return [Math.ceil(extent[0]), Math.floor(extent[1])];
  }

  function updateAxes(extent) {
    primaryXAxis.scale(primaryChart.xScale());

    primaryXAxis.domain(extent);

    g
      .select('.nv-primary .nv-x.nv-axis')
      .transition()
      .duration(transitionDuration)
      .call(primaryXAxis);
    g
      .select('.nv-secondary .nv-ySecondary.nv-axis')
      .transition()
      .duration(transitionDuration)
      .call(yAxisSecondary);
    g
      .select('.nv-primary .nv-yPrimary.nv-axis')
      .transition()
      .duration(transitionDuration)
      .call(yAxisPrimary);
  }

  function updateChartData(currentExtent, dataPrimary, dataSecondary) {
    updateAxes(currentExtent);

    var primaryDatasetsWithinBrushExtent = !dataPrimary.length
      ? [
        {
          values: []
        }
      ]
      : dataPrimary.map(function(d) {
        var restrictedDataset = Object.assign({}, d);
        restrictedDataset.values = d.values.filter(function(d, i) {
          return (
              primaryChart.x()(d, i) >= currentExtent[0] &&
              primaryChart.x()(d, i) <= currentExtent[1]
          );
        });
        return restrictedDataset;
      });

    var primaryChartWrap = g
      .select('.nv-primary .nv-linesWrap')
      .datum(primaryDatasetsWithinBrushExtent);

    var secondaryDatasetsWithinExtent = !dataSecondary.length
      ? [
        {
          values: []
        }
      ]
      : dataSecondary.map(function(d) {
        var restrictedDataset = Object.assign({}, d);
        restrictedDataset.values = d.values.filter(function(d, i) {
          return (
              secondaryChart.x()(d, i) >= currentExtent[0] &&
              secondaryChart.x()(d, i) <= currentExtent[1]
          );
        });
        return restrictedDataset;
      });
    var focusSecondaryChartWrap = g
      .select('.nv-secondary .nv-secondaryChartWrap')
      .datum(secondaryDatasetsWithinExtent);

    primaryChart.xDomain(currentExtent);
    secondaryChart.xDomain(currentExtent);

    primaryChartWrap
      .transition()
      .duration(transitionDuration)
      .call(primaryChart);

    focusSecondaryChartWrap
      .transition()
      .duration(transitionDuration)
      .call(secondaryChart);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue was that I was trying to set the xDomain in multiple locations. This seems to mess up NVD3's logic. After I removed all of the .domain/.xDomain it worked perfectly :)

Debugging approach was to carefully read through the lineChart.js code and notice what it didn't have that I had.